# Pytorch tensor resizing much slower than Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I'm comparing the performance of resizing in Pytorch with Tensorflow. The result is quite significant. For the same image, the difference is about 3x:

## Pytorch

```
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torch.nn.functional as F

IMAGE1 = '1647524904_19.jpg'
img1 = Image.open(IMAGE1)
img1 = T.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1)(img1)
prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()
k = 3
for i in range(5000):
    x = torch.from_numpy(np.array(img1)).permute(0, 1).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).float()
    img1r = F.interpolate(x, size=((int) (img1.size[1]/k), (int) (img1.size[0]/k)))
    
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - prev_time)
        prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# 0:00:01.075056
# 0:00:01.024509
# 0:00:00.979186
# 0:00:00.983568
```

## Tensorflow

```
IMAGE1 = '1647524904_19.jpg'
img1 = tf.image.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(IMAGE1))
img1 = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img1)
k = 3
prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(5000):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        img1r = tf.image.resize(image1, [(int) (img1.shape[0]/k), (int) (image1.shape[1]/k)])
  
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - prev_time)
        prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# 0:00:00.383906
# 0:00:00.287261
# 0:00:00.287848
# 0:00:00.286864
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Does anyone know why the difference in performance is so large?

EDIT:

If everything is moved inside the loop, Pytorch still underperforms Tensorflow:

## Pytorch

```
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torch.nn.functional as F

IMAGE1 = '1647524904_19.jpg'
prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()
k = 3
for i in range(5000):
    img1 = Image.open(IMAGE1)
    img1 = T.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1)(img1)
    x = torch.from_numpy(np.array(img1)).permute(0, 1).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).float()
    img1r = F.interpolate(x, size=((int) (img1.size[1]/k), (int) (img1.size[0]/k)))

    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - prev_time)
        prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# 0:00:04.559505
# 0:00:04.408138
# 0:00:04.259362
# 0:00:04.842845
```

## Tensorflow

```
IMAGE1 = '1647524904_19.jpg'

k = 3
prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(5000):
    img1 = tf.image.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(IMAGE1))
    img1 = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img1)
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        img1r = tf.image.resize(image1, [(int) (img1.shape[0]/k), (int) (image1.shape[1]/k)])
  
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - prev_time)
        prev_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# 0:00:03.908698
# 0:00:03.914131
# 0:00:03.956090
# 0:00:03.893828
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Sorry I left out `import torch.nn.functional as F`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny `size=((int) (img1.size[1]/k), ...` runs fine on my end in a jupyter notebook. I've added the image.

Comment: You are correct. It's not a tensor, it's a PIL Image. I tested with a tensor.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I've added the image IO and tensor resizing in the loop and Pytorch is about 20% slower.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I'm trying to compare the performances so I think it'd be fair to have everything inside the loop.

Comment: Than it might be fairer to use the native `torchvision` functions `torchvision.io.read_image` and `torchvision.transforms.Resize` to avoid conversions, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks. `torchvision` indeed performs better.